# Ruby on rails: refreshing results from foo.bars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So this is what I have, it is function in models/product.rb

```
def get_current_offer_price()
    if self.prices.blank?
      p = Price.new()
      p.product = self
      p.value = (Amazon.get_price_by_asin(self.code)).to_d / 100
      p.save
    end
    self.prices.last.value
  end
```

Interestingly enough, the first time I run this the system crashes, but if I refresh the page, and every single other time, this works perfectly.  It seems like self.prices isn't updating between the p.save and when I call it next, but it later figures it out.  Is there a way I can force a refresh before the page finishes loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  def get_current_offer_price
    if self.prices.blank?
      self.prices.create :value => (Amazon.get_price_by_asin(self.code)).to_d / 100
    end
    self.prices.last.value
  end
```

It's usually a good idea to use the association proxy to create associated objects.  This avoids your problem, which is caused by the association proxy caching it's prices.  You create a new object, but the cached value doesn't pick it up.

Using the association to create the associated object, invalidates the cache and causes it to be fetched a new.  You also dont have to manually assign any primary keys, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your method, and use `create` method, something like this:

```
def get_current_offer_price()
    if self.prices.blank?
      product_id = self.id
      product_value = (Amazon.get_price_by_asin(self.code)).to_d / 100
      Price.create(:product_id => product_id, :product_value => product_value)
    end
    self.prices.last.value
end
```